Bootstrap overflow container's list items
How do I make this dropdown list's each item to be shown in full length single line, instead wrapping the text?


.autocomplete-items {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
    /* border-top: none; */
    /* border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; */
    z-index: 100;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
/*     width: auto; */
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.autocomplete-items .item {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
  width: auto;
  overflow:auto;
}

.autocomplete-items .item:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.autocomplete-items .item.active {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w-100 h-100 py-3">
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <div>
                    <div class="row my-3">
                        <div class="col"><input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" max_length="25" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control" required="yes" ></div>
                        <div class="col"><input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" max_length="25" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control" required="yes" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row my-3">
                        <div class="col">
                        <select name="Country" id="Country" class="form-control, form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <option value="US">United States</option>
                          <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col position-relative"><input type="text" name="Place" id="Place" label=" Place" max_length="25" list="PlaceSelect" autocomplete="off" placeholder=" City" class="form-control" required="" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true" >
                        
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 position-absolute">
                                <ul class="autocomplete-items m-0 p-0 border" id="PlaceSelect" style="display: block;">
                                <li class="item">New York City, Long: -74.005970, Lati: 40.714270, TZ: America/New_York, Population: 8804190</li>
                                <li class="item">New South Memphis, Long: -90.056760, Lati: 35.086760, TZ: America/Chicago, Population: 641608</li>
                                <li class="item">New Orleans, Long: -90.075070, Lati: 29.954650, TZ: America/Chicago, Population: 389617</li>
                                <li class="item">Newark, Long: -74.172370, Lati: 40.735660, TZ: America/New_York, Population: 281944</li>
                                <li class="item">Newport News, Long: -76.429750, Lati: 36.980380, TZ: America/New_York, Population: 182385</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="col "><input type="number" name="Population" label="Zipcode" id="Zipcode" max_length="25" step="0.000001" min="-180" max="180" placeholder="Zipcode" class="form-control" required="yes" ></div>
                        <div class="col"><input type="number" name="Cost" label="Cost" id="Cost" max_length="25" step="0.000001" min="-180" max="180" placeholder="Cost" class="form-control" required="yes" ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        




@Paulie_D Each dropdown ul li item in the list to show in a single line instead of wrapping.

Just add   white-space: nowrap; to your .item class


.autocomplete-items {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
  /* border-top: none; */
  /* border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; */
  z-index: 100;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*     width: auto; */
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.autocomplete-items .item {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.autocomplete-items .item:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.autocomplete-items .item.active {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w-100 h-100 py-3">
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <div>
      <div class="row my-3">
        <div class="col"><input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" max_length="25" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control" required="yes"></div>
        <div class="col"><input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" max_length="25" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control" required="yes"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row my-3">
        <div class="col">
          <select name="Country" id="Country" class="form-control, form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col position-relative"><input type="text" name="Place" id="Place" label=" Place" max_length="25" list="PlaceSelect" autocomplete="off" placeholder=" City" class="form-control" required="" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true">

          <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 position-absolute">
            <ul class="autocomplete-items m-0 p-0 border" id="PlaceSelect" style="display: block;">
              <li class="item">New York City, Long: -74.005970, Lati: 40.714270, TZ: America/New_York, Population: 8804190</li>
              <li class="item">New South Memphis, Long: -90.056760, Lati: 35.086760, TZ: America/Chicago, Population: 641608</li>
              <li class="item">New Orleans, Long: -90.075070, Lati: 29.954650, TZ: America/Chicago, Population: 389617</li>
              <li class="item">Newark, Long: -74.172370, Lati: 40.735660, TZ: America/New_York, Population: 281944</li>
              <li class="item">Newport News, Long: -76.429750, Lati: 36.980380, TZ: America/New_York, Population: 182385</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col "><input type="number" name="Population" label="Zipcode" id="Zipcode" max_length="25" step="0.000001" min="-180" max="180" placeholder="Zipcode" class="form-control" required="yes"></div>
        <div class="col"><input type="number" name="Cost" label="Cost" id="Cost" max_length="25" step="0.000001" min="-180" max="180" placeholder="Cost" class="form-control" required="yes"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>




Perfect. Thank you!
